# mathematical analysis pre calculus

Tags: real-analysis

I was going through ia maron calculus recently and found this : prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is an irrational number.

I proceeded the following way:-

a) Assume $\sqrt 3+ \sqrt 2 = A$ is a rational number.

b) $\sqrt 3 = A-\sqrt2$;

c) $3= A^2 + 2 -2A \sqrt 2$ (squaring both sides)

d) $\Rightarrow A^2= 1+2A \sqrt 2$;

e) we know that $\sqrt 2$ is an irrational number, so $2A \sqrt 2$ in d) is an irrational number (we assumed $A$ as rational, so $2A$ is also rational and $2A \sqrt 2$ will be irrational since the product of a non-zero rational and irrational is irrational(Note $A\neq 0$ since $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 \neq 0$).

Now $1+2A \sqrt 2$ is irrational since the sum of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational...(here 1 is rational)

f) since $A$ is rational , $A^2$ must be rational but the right side of d) is an irrational number (from e), which contradicts the assumption and thus $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2=A$ is an irrational number.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: It's correct. ${}{}$

Comment: Although your approach is correct, if I was you I would add a proof that the sum of a rational and an irrational is in fact irrational. The proof is simple and many versions of it can be found online. If you feel its unnecessary, then maybe just look it up for your own benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. This is an alternative proof.

If $q:=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}>0$ is rational then also $\frac{1}{2}\left(q-\frac{1}{q}\right)$ is rational. 
But this is a contradiction because
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(q-\frac{1}{q}\right)=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{3-2}\right)
=\sqrt{2}\not \in \mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: @Gustav Friedriech Wilhelm Any further doubt?